# Not recieving the test message in FCM

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use FCM to make push notifications but when I use the FCM test notification system, I don't recieve any notification. I don't think I need any code for that purpose except for my registration token which I obtain like this

```
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I then store it in a database and copy-paste it so that there is no change. But still I am not recieving any notification. I even added the onMessageRecieved function

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...


        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {


                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
           // Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
    public void handleNow(String body) {
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"Alerts")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Stice Alerts")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(body));
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
    }
```

Here is my notification channel

```
   private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Alerts";
            String description = "For alerts when someone is going";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Alerts",name,importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

My android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.jobifyme">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DeleteTask"/>
        <activity android:name=".OurTeam" />
        <activity android:name=".TaskView" />
        <activity android:name=".AddAlert" />
        <activity android:name=".AddTask" />
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".TaskList"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.jobifyme.FirstScreen" >

        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.jobifyme.FirstScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FirstScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".StartingPage" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.Alerts"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: if you are using android above API 28, add a channel

Comment: Already done. Editing my code to show it

Comment: Oh thanks Erwin. I checked my code and I had a problem with my channel creation. Thanks for the help

Comment: nice, then are you getting the notification?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the notification now. Just need to see how to send notifications from a device. I have posted a stack for that too as these are the only 2 things I was struggling on

Comment: Is it wrong to edit my post and make it a different question since I can only post 1 question every 90 minutes

Comment: Im not sure about that, if its related i think you can

Answer (score 0):

While sending out your notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging, make sure the channel set is equal to your channel name `Alerts`

Comment: From where I am sending message, I only get the option for heading, text, image, token ID and notification name

Comment: If that is Firebase under additional options there's Android Notification Channel make that Alert or alternatively you can change your code to 
```NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"fcm_default_channel")```
This will pick up the default FCM channel.